# System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable'

Tags: c#, mono

I'm using monodevelop to make a program in C# in Linux. when I try to build the program this error comes out:

> Build FAILED. Errors:
>
> /home/interpuls/importcsv/utilities/TotalMilk/TotalMilk/TotalMilk.csproj
>   (default targets) ->
>   /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile
>   target) ->
>
> ```
>     MyDb.cs(126,16): error CS0012: The type `System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable' is defined in an assembly
> ```
>
> that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly
>   `System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>
> ```
>      0 Warning(s)
>      1 Error(s)
> ```

I've already added `System.xml`, `System.xml.linq` and `System.xml.serialization` but nothing changed. Can anyone can tell me what should I do ?

Comment: Could you verify the version of `System.Xml` you added a reference to is actually 4.0.0?

Comment: I Solved , i deleted some of the system library on visual studio before to transfer the program to mono

Comment: what version of mono and monodevelop are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like in "MyDb.cs" you've tried to make something serializable.

If that's the case you need to add a reference to "System.Xml" (ie using System.Xml) or you could remove whatever is trying to access it at line 126.

There may be extra work to add the ref in MonoDevelop. I'm unsure.